# Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem for General Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Though $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, because of LUB axiom one can conclude BW theorem i.e (every bounded sequence will have a convergent subsequence.)

My questions are:-

1. In what kind of Metric Spaces this result will hold?
   (example: In Compact Metric Spaces this holds.)
   Is there a charaterization to these spaces ?
2. Can we find an example of a **Unbounded Metric Space(like $\mathbb{R}$) where BW property holds?**
3. In what kind of Metric Space it is true that **Every bounded sequence will have a Cauchy subsequence.** (example: In Totally Bounded Metric Space this holds.) Is there a characterization to these spaces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here.

- A metric space in which every Cauchy sequence converges is called complete.
- A metric space in which every sequence has a Cauchy subsequence is equivalent to the space being totally bounded.

So what you need is a complete metric space in which every bounded subset is totally bounded.

Examples are: any compact metric space, any Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, any closed subspace of a Euclidean space.

In general this property is called the [Heine-Borel property](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem).

Comment: A metric space is totally bounded if and only if every sequence has a *Cauchy* subsequence.

Comment: Thank you, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

The category of metric spaces you are looking for are those in which every closed bounded subset is compact (this property is called the Heine-Borel property).

You know that if a metric space, $(X,d)$, is compact, then every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence (this is known as sequential compactness). The converse is also true, by which I mean if a metric space is sequentially compact, then it is also compact.

First, suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space in which every closed bounded subspace is compact. Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a bounded sequence in $X$. Because this sequence is bounded, we have for some $\epsilon>0$ that $d(a_1,a_i)<\epsilon\;\forall\; i$. This means $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset B(a_1;\epsilon)\subset \overline{B(a_1;\epsilon)}$.

$Y=\overline{B(a_1;\epsilon)}$ is clearly a closed subset of $X$. It is also clearly bounded (all points are at most a distance $2\epsilon$ apart by the triangle inequality). So $Y$ is a compact subset of $X$. As a subspace of $X$, $Y$ is also a metric space. So in its own right, $Y$ is a compact metric space. Since all points of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ lie in $Y$, there is some subsequence $(a_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which converges in $Y$. As $Y\subset X$, the subsequence $(a_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $X$ as well, so $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence in $X$, as desired.

For the other direction, suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space in which every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. Let $A$ be any closed and bounded subset of $X$. We note immediately that $A$, being a subspace of $X$, can be treated as a metric space in its own right. Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of points in $A$. As $A$ is a bounded subset of $X$, $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence of $X$. By assumption then, there is some subsequence, $(a_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$, converging to some point $z\in X$. Since all elements of $(a_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ lie in $A$ and $A$ is closed in $X$, it follows that $z$ belongs to $A$. So $(a_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a convergent subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $A$, i.e. every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence in $A$. This makes $A$ sequentially compact, and hence compact. As $A$ was an arbitrary closed bounded subset of $X$, all closed bounded subsets of $X$ are compact.

By the Heine-Borel theorem, all metric spaces $(\mathbb R^n,d)$ possess this Heine-Borel property (where $d$ can be either the standard Euclidean metric or the [Chebyshev distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)). The metric spaces that satisfy the requirements of your second question are then exactly like euclidean space, in that they'll be noncompact spaces with the Heine-Borel property. It is also true that any noncompact space $(X,d)$ has at least one unbounded metric $d'$ that preserves its topology, but this doesn't guarantee that if $(X,d)$ has the Heine-Borel property, then $(X,d')$ does too (because different metrics create different bounded sets).

Regarding your third question, since in a metric spaces with the Heine-Borel property all bounded sequences have convergent subsequences, all bounded sequences also have Cauchy subsequences (because any convergent subsequence is trivially Cauchy). So all metric spaces with the Heine-Borel property satisfy the requirements of your 3rd question. Whether these are the only spaces that do, I don't know. It seems unlikely, but I cannot think of a good counterexample.

**EDIT** (due to OP/ Saikat Goswami's comment): Yes, many more spaces than just those with the Heine-Borel property satisfy the requirements of the third question. Working off OP's comment under this answer, more generally any subspace of a Heine-Borel space will satisfy the requirements of a third question (like the example of $(0,1)$ as a subspace of $(\mathbb R,d)$ where $d$ is the standard metric on the reals). The complete characterization of the spaces satisfying the third question is by the criteria in Jacob FG's answer: they are exactly the metric spaces in which all bounded sets are totally bounded.

Comment: Regarding the 3rd question. (0,1) is a metric space with induced metric from $\mathbb{R}$. This does not have the BW property. But satisfies the condition stated in question 3. So definitely the class in question 3 is bigger than the class in question 1.

Comment: @SaikatGoswami Yes, I thought I was missing some obvious example. Fair point. I have edited my answer to account for this.